# How to combine different variables

Tags: r

I am trying to combine two different variables using R. I might be searching for the wrong thing, but I cant find an answer to this question and I am an R novice. Basically I am trying to turn this:

Variable X {1, 3, 5},

Variable Y {2, 4, 6}

Into this:

Variable New{1,3,5,2,4,6}.

The data is a .svs file. 
 I am having a lot of difficulty finding out how to do this. Any help or links to previous threads would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
x <- c(1,3,5)
y <- c(2,4,6)
c(x,y) # this will make a vector out of x and y
```